# Wrap dynamically created html element with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically created bootstrap menu links.

```
foreach (var link in links)
{
  <li data-name="@link.Dropdown" ><a href="@Url.Action(link.Action, link.Controller, new { area = link.Area })">@Html.Raw(link.Icon) @link.LinkName</a></li>
}
```

Some of the links should be dropdown, so i tried to wrap them like that

```
$('li[data-name=School]').wrapAll("<li class='dropdown'>" +
                 "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></i> School <b class='caret'></b></a>" +
                 "<ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></li>");
```

I want to insert the matching elements between `<ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>`, but it inserts between `<i></i>`. I tried this way too:

```
    $('li[data-name=School]').wrapAll("<ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>").before("<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> School <b class='caret'></b></a>").wrapAll("<li class='dropdown'></li>");
```

Comment: Insert the glyph `i` element afterwards. Wrapping assume the content goes into the innermost element (which is the `<i>`). A practical example of your output HTML would go a long way on this one (for mocking up a JSFiddle etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrappings assume the content goes into the innermost element. Your wrapper has two inner elements so it would be difficult for it to chose the last one (which is what you want). Instead it targets the first one (which is the `<i>`).

Step one, wrap the element in the new `UL`/`LI`:

```
$('li[data-name=School]').wrapAll("<li class='dropdown'><ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></li>");
```

Step two, add back the new link:

```
.closest('.dropdown').prepend("<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></i> School <b class='caret'></b></a>");
```

Which together is simply:

```
$('li[data-name=School]').wrapAll("<li class='dropdown'><ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></li>").closest('.dropdown').prepend("<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></i> School <b class='caret'></b></a>");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/eLgokpd1/

Comment: @Mike Debela: No problem. I was waiting for a database update so had 5 mins :)